# O React é capaz de automaticamente remover eventListeners dos Refs quando o componente é destruído?

Tags: javascript, react, web-component

Possuo um input de um `web components` que para receber o valor inputado, devo criar uma `Ref` para esse input e adicionar um `eventListener`, respectivamente:

```
 const nameInputRef = useRef(null)
 const [userName, setUserName] = useState('')
```

Criei um `useEffect` para que quando o componente iniciar, ele adicionar um `eventListener` nesse `ref`. Assim consigo gerenciar a troca de estado do meu `web component` para meu componente React:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    nameInputRef.current.addEventListener(
      'inputChangedValue',
      ({ target: { value } }) => {
        fields.username.input.onChange(value)
      }
    )
  }, [])
```

Minha dúvida é: O React é capaz de automaticamente remover este EventListener quando o componente é destruído?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não. O React não é capaz de determinar que você sequer criou um *event listener* dentro de um `useEffect`.

Nesse tipo de caso, o que você precisa fazer é utilizar uma função retornada do *callback* do `useEffect` para remover o *listener* que você criou anteriormente, manualmente. Assim:

```
function handleEvent({ target: { value } }) {
  fields.username.input.onChange(value);
}

useEffect(() => {
  const current = nameInputRef.current;
  if (!current) { // Garante que não tentaremos acessar um valor nulo.
    return;
  }
  current.addEventListener('inputChangedValue', handleEvent);
  return () => current.removeEventListener('inputChangedValue', handleEvent);
}, []);
```

Repare que tive que mover o *callback* do evento para uma função externa ao `useEffect`. Isso é necessário porque o `removeEventListener` espera uma referência à função para que possa remover o evento.

Referir à documentação para entender como funcionam os chamados [efeitos com *cleanup*](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

Se for algo muito repetitivo, talvez valha a pena criar um *hook* customizado para extrair o *boilerplate* repetitivo para gerir a adição e limpeza dos *event listeners*.